# multi-selection on hosted wwf4 designer

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

...using wwf4, VS2010

a co-worker built an app that host WWF4, he did a good job and I generally trust his skills.  The one annoyance is that I can't move more than one object on the designer surface at a time, which means modifying the layout of a moderately complex workflow is a major PITA.

He says that he tried, but came to the conclusion that you could not do anything with the wwf design surface.  He's good and I trust his words, but I'm older... anything can be done.

what are my options for implementing 
1. drag and select
2. multi-object move via the keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your co-worker is right, there's no support for it at all. The designer will be greatly improved with .NET 4.5.

Read this: [What's New in Windows Workflow Foundation in .NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh305677%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> ***Multi-select***
>
> - *Multiple activities can be selected at one time, either by dragging a
>     rectangle around them (when pan mode is not enabled), or by holding
>     down Ctrl.*
> - *Multiple activity selections can also be dragged and dropped within
>     the designer, and can also be interacted with using the context menu.*

[Microsoft® .NET Framework® 4.5 Beta](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28978)